# How to get SQLite one column data to plain int?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

SQLite whole column with numbers convert to plain `int`, because I want to perform a calculation.

I get a whole of data from one column by convert data to `ArrayList<String>` and is there any simpler way to do this instead steps: `ArrayList<String>` -> `ArrayList<int>` -> `int`?

```
public ArrayList<String> GetAllValues(String aTable,String[] aColumn)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(aTable, aColumn, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            list.add(cursor.getString(0));
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())
    {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: If it's an integer column, use an `ArrayList<Integer>` and use`cursor.getInt(0)` instead.

Comment: You could perform the calculation inside the database, and get the calculation result as an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Because `int` is a primitive type and `ArrayList` only takes objects you can't create an `ArrayList<int>` but you can create an `ArrayList<Integer>`. In this case read out the values with `cursor.getInt()`. If you need an array of primitive `int[]` you can either just create an `int[]` array with the size `cursor.getCount()` or by iterating through the ArrayList afterwards and putting each item in an array of the size of your `ArrayList.size()`. If it's not an Integer column, and you're sure it can be converted to `int` use `parseInt(cursor.getString())`.